# Difficulty concerting coordinates system of data frame to raster coordinate system (trasformation) in R

Tags: r

Can someone help me understand why I have issue getting my dataframe (point coordinates into the same coordinate with my Raster data?

### My dataframe with point files (lets call it trainData_crs)

```
trainData_crs<- read.csv(file.csv)  

class(trainData_crs)
[1] "data.frame"
```

### The data frame had no coordinate system

```
crs(trainData_crs)
[1] NA




summary(trainData_crs)
 PlotType      Class                      Latitude       Longitude    
 closedforest:22   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :17.81   Min.   :24.72  
 grass       :34   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:17.86   1st Qu.:24.98  
 lowforest   :24   Median :3.000   Median :17.92   Median :25.02  
 mediumforest:26   Mean   :2.904   Mean   :17.95   Mean   :25.02  
 shrubs      : 4   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:18.01   3rd Qu.:25.10  
 unknown     : 3   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :18.46   Max.   :25.16  
 water       : 1
```

### Create a TIFF raster and convert it to Rasterbricks

```
all_landsat_bands<-list.files ("file.tif")

img <- brick(all_landsat_bands)

img <- brick(LandsatAprJune_2019_st)
 class(img)
[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
 names(img)
[1] "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B10" "B11"
```

### First convert data frame to Latitude and Longitude coordinate numbers

```
coordinates(trainData_crs)<-~Latitude +Longitude

proj4string(trainData_crs) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

### Convert to same projection

```
trainData_crs_sp <- spTransform(trainData_crs, crs(img))
```

### Confirm if points and image are in same coordinates

```
crs(trainData_crs_sp)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=utm +zone=34 +south +a=6378249.145 +b=6356514.966398753 +towgs84=-138,-105,-289,0,0,0,0 +units=m
+no_defs 

 crs(img)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=utm +zone=34 +south +a=6378249.145 +b=6356514.966398753 +towgs84=-138,-105,-289,0,0,0,0 +units=m
+no_defs
```

### Plot them to  check if the points overlap with rasterBrick

```
plotRGB(img,
    r = 4, g = 3, b = 2,
    stretch = "lin",
    scale=1000,
    axes = TRUE,
    main = "RGB composite image\n Landsat Bands 7, 3, 2"); plot(trainData_crs_sp, add=T)
```

But the difficulty that I have is that, even after converting the dataframe of points to rasterbrick coordinates, they still do not fall in the same area or overlap.

Comment: Can you please show us the results of `sp::bbox(trainData_crs_sp)` and `raster::extent(img)`?

Answer (score 0):

A data.frame will not have a CRS unless it is turned into a spatial object.

Your workflow should look like this, I am using the `sf` library here instead of `sp` since it's more up to date. The next step is figuring out what your CRS should be for the trainData, which may come from your metadata or whoever collected the data. In your example above, it looks like you are incorrectly assigning the CRS using the `proj4string` instead of `CRS` in `sp`.

```
trainData_crs<- read.csv(file.csv) 

trainData_sf<-st_as_sf(trainData_crs, coords=c("Latitude","Longitude"), crs="+init=epsg:4326")
```

Then to project use `st_transform` based on the projection that your raster is in.

Comment: The op is turning the data.frame into a spatial object, just using the sp library rather than sf. All you are doing here is showing an identical workflow in sf.